# Issue when centering two-lines text in a RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button

I've got a `RadioGroup` with several `RadioButtons` in it. When the text in the RadioButton has two lines I get an unwanted top margin for my RadioButton.

Anybody could help?

**UPDATE**

I tried to set the padding of the RadioButtons to 0, I also tried with LinearLayout and Buttons. Nothing works...

[image]
[image]

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/filter_bar"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_filter"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/btn_filter_1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter_1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_filter"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/filter_1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_filter_2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_filter"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/filter_2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <!-- 3 more RadioButtons -->

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: setMarginTop="0dp"
PaddingTop="0dp"
MarginBottom="5dp"
PaddingBottom="5dp"

Comment: @BB Expert: I don't want any margin/padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setGravity%28int%29) SetGravity is specifies how to align the text by the view's x- and/or y-axis when the text is smaller than the view. This is not the case here.

Comment: The text doesn't seem larger than the view. And why would that add a margin at the top?

Comment: Perhaps you could use some [layout params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) like : `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: I set `android:gravity="center_vertical"` (not layout_gravity) in my `RadioGroup`, and it works. I'll accept your answer because it helped me find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: All these layouting issues are sometimes really tricky :) Thanks!